# I need "ONLY" the BottomSheet to ignore the keyboard

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In the screen below, I have the following text "By creating an account ...." that I would like to always keep at the bottom of the screen and should never scroll up with the keyboard.

Currently the text is placed in bottom sheet but unfortunately, the bottom sheet does scroll up with the keyboard.

Using resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false in the Scaffold will not help since it will make all screen ignore the keyboard.

Is there any way to keep the text at the bottom of the screen and have it ignore the keyboard?

[image]

Comment: is there any input fields in the bottom sheet

Comment: no there is no input in the bottom sheet. However there is an in put in the screen

Comment: I am unable to understand your issue..can you please share us issue images if possible?

Comment: I attached a screen to clarify

Comment: that is not the bottom sheet FYI. the bottom navigation bar and bottom sheet both are different. mention clearly to get correct answers.

Comment: I am aware that the bottom navigation is different than the bottom sheet. But I was not able to solve the problem using bottom sheet  so I used bottom navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a basic solution to this.

I placed the terms and conditions text in the bottomNavigationBar property of the Scaffold like this.

```
Scaffold(
   bottomNavigationBar: const TermsAndConditionsText(),
....
....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`
The value of `.bottom` will be updated whenever the Keyboard shows up.

To achieve what you want
1- Define the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in the Scaffold.
2- Wrap your "form" in a `Stack` widget.
3- Add your Widgets which should stick at the bottom of the screen at the same level of your "form" in an `Align` or `Positioned`

```
Stack(
  children: [
    child: Column(
      ... //Form
    ),
    const Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Text("Terms And Conditions"),
    )
  ],
),
```

4- And now the magic trick : wrap your "form" in a `Padding` with the `viewInsets.bottom` value

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
      ),
      child: Column(
        ...// Form
      ),
    ),
    const Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Text("Terms and Conditions"),
    )
  ],
),
```

My solution looks more like a "hack" than a proper solution, but I never found any official documentation solving this kind of "problem".